# Navigating a complicated array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am trying to loop through and access data in this array. I seem to be getting error messages about stdclass.

I assigned the data to $activites and I thought I could use something like $activites[0]->fuel to get that value but it seems not?

```
object(stdClass)#35 (2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(25) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#36 (13) {
      ["activityId"]=>
      string(36) "47d7f2f1-2657-4dca-b30d-54358e251b10"
      ["calories"]=>
      int(171)
      ["fuel"]=>
      int(368)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#37 (13) {
      ["activityId"]=>
      string(36) "b1281a77-13e9-4b2b-96d2-82f390c8969f"
      ["calories"]=>
      int(275)
      ["fuel"]=>
      int(591)
    }
```

Comment: How are you creating your array in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$yourObject->data[0]->fuel`